# Web and mobile site creation - just starting on this project

Tags: mobile

I need to build both a website and a mobile site (starting from scratch).  The website will include a registration/login, user upload, and sharing feature.  I would like to have all of these features available in the mobile site as well.   Any recommendations on the best starting approach would be appreciated.  For example, should I create the website from start to finish before even starting to think about the mobile site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you design your server side code correctly, you should be able to use those components no matter where the client is.   You would just have to write a thin wrapper for each different interaction type, e.g. xml vs json.

Its hard to say more without knowing exactly what you are doing, and how many people you have working on this?  You can finish the desktop version before you start the mobile, but you don't have to.  Depending on team size/skill you could develop both concurrently...